# Does "locate" mean "find" or "place" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, verbs

In the sentence *"to locate (a curve) by plotted points"* which I found in one of the definitions for the verb "plot" does the verb **"locate"** mean..

1. **to** **find or discover** the exact position of something:
   Archeologists have located the remains of an ancient temple.
2. **to put** or establish something **in a particular place**:
   [ T ] The company decided to locate its headquarters in Denver.

?

It seems to me that both possibilities are feasible although the second is less. Is this the kind of sentence that a native speaker readily knows which one of these possibilities is correct?

Comment: I think the second, with the observation that in e.g. geometry we can locate (specify the location of) a figure by stating some numbers, e.g. I can locate a circle on the x, y plane by stating the x and y co-ordinates of its centre, and its radius.

Comment: This is a rather technical use of the word.  There is a kind of philosophical distinction when applied to mathematical objects.  Does the curve of y=x² exist before you have plotted it?  Do you create the curve, or are you just indicating where that curve always was?  Is a curve just the pencil mark, or is it a mathematical object, that is as immaterial as "5".

Comment: Anyway, this use is technical and doesn't match either of the two dictionary definitions you give.  It's use derives from geometry, and the notion of finding or placing a point where two lines or curves meet.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not “the kind of sentence that a native speaker readily knows which one of these possibilities is correct.” I’m a native speaker of American English who happens to be a mathematician, and without more context the scrap that OP cites does not have a single unambiguous interpretation.